# I wanna include html file on post! But Liquid say "Could not locate the included file."

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I wanna include some HTML file on post!
I wanna show a reference on the right side of my blog.
Reference is HTML file, and it looks like simple doc.

So I created the layout file `jekyll.html` and I wrote a tag `<div>`.
Then I added a header variable to my post and reference file is located on `_layouts`.

This is the code in `jekyll.html`:

```
<div class="right">
  {% for ref in page.refs %}
    {% include ref %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And this code post's YAML header.

```
---
layout: jekyll
title:  "02. "
date:   2018-12-30 14:38:42 +0900
category: Jekyll
refs: [ bundler.html, test.html ]
---
```

So, Liquid says:

> Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'ref' in any of `["E:/Projects/Jekyll/_includes"]`. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source. in `/_layouts/jekyll.html`

What's wrong? Did I do anything wrong?
Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a liquid variable in an include tag, you must surround it with curly braces :

```
{% include {{ ref }} %}
```